# log and poisson-like integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Here is a fun looking one some may enjoy.

Show that:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\frac{x^{2}+2x\cos(a)+1}{x^{2}-2x\cos(a)+1}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx=\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}-\pi a$$

Comment: The LHS is a periodic function of $\large a$ which is not consistent with the RHS. In addition, the LHS is an even function of $\large a$.

Answer (score 7):

Starting from
$$
{\rm Log}(1+x e^{ia})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}e^{ina}}{n}x^n
$$
we see that
$$
\int_0^1{\rm Log}(1+x e^{ia})\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}e^{ina}}{n^2}
$$
Taking real parts we get
$$
\int_0^1 \log|1+x e^{ia}|\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\cos(na)}{n^2}
$$
applying this to $a+\pi$ instead of $a$ we obtain also
$$
\int_0^1 \log|1-x e^{ia}|\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(na)}{n^2}
$$
Subtracting these two formulas:
$$
\int_0^1 \log\frac{|1+x e^{ia}|}{|1-x e^{ia}|}\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{((-1)^{n-1}+1)\cos(na)}{n^2}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2\cos((2n+1)a)}{(2n+1)^2}
$$
or
$$
\int_0^1 \log\left(\frac{1+2x\cos(a)+x^2}{ 1-2x \cos(a)+x^2 }\right)\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{4\cos((2n+1)a)}{(2n+1)^2}\tag{1}
$$
On the other hand if $f$ is the $2\pi$-periodic **even** function that coincides with $a\mapsto \frac{\pi^2}{2}-\pi a$ on $[0,\pi]$ then it is straightforward to check that the Fourier series expansion of $f$ coincides with the right side of $(1)$. So, we have shown that
$$
\int_0^1 \log\left(\frac{1+2x\cos(a)+x^2}{ 1-2x \cos(a)+x^2 }\right)\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx
=\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\pi |a|
$$
for $a\in[-\pi,\pi]$.$\qquad\square$

Answer (score 4):

Denote
$$
I(r)
=\int_{0}^{1}\log\left(\frac{x^{2}+2x r +1}{x^{2}-2x r+1}\right)\cdot \frac{1}{x}dx
$$
then 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dI}{dr}
&=\int_0^1 \frac{4 \left(x^2+1\right)}{\left(2-4 r^2\right) x^2+x^4+1} dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{2}{x^2+2rx+1}+\frac{2}{x^2-2 r x+1} \right)dx\\
&=\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x+r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\Biggl|_0^1
+\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\Biggl|_0^1\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x+r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\right)\right)\Biggl|_0^1\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{\frac{x+r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}+\frac{x-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}}{1-\frac{x+r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\frac{x-r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}}\Biggl|_0^1\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\tan^{-1}\frac{2x\sqrt{1-r^2}}{1-x^2}\Biggl|_0^1\\
&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\\
\end{align}
$$
Since $I(0)=0$, then
$$
I(\cos a)=I(0)+\int_0^{\cos a} \frac{dI}{dr}dr=\int_0^{\cos a}\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr=\pi\sin^{-1}s|_0^{\cos a}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}-\pi a
$$

Comment: i am wondering how did this receive a downvote ... i doing same except differentiated w.r.t. $a$.

Comment: @SantoshLinkha, then you may upvote :) After long time I understood that there is no point in asking "why the downvote?", "downvoter, explain what's wrong". In most cases you won't get respond.

Comment: who upvoted both answers along with the question?? me ... of course!! :D

Comment: both solutions are very nice and clever. Whomever downvoted must have done it just to be a *****.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x^{2} + 2x\cos\pars{a} + 1
     \over x^{2} - 2x\cos\pars{a} + 1}\,{\dd x \over x}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &x^{2} + 2\cos\pars{a}x + 1\quad\mbox{has roots}\quad
> -p\quad\mbox{and}\quad -p^{*}\quad\mbox{where}\quad p \equiv \expo{\ic a}
> \\[3mm]&\mbox{Similarly,}\quad
> x^{2} - 2\cos\pars{a}x + 1\quad\mbox{has roots at}\quad p\quad\mbox{and}\quad p^{*}.\qquad
> \mbox{Note that}\quad pp^{*} = 1.
> \end{align}

Then, with $\ds{0 < \epsilon < 1}$:
\begin{align}
&\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\pars{x^{2} + 2x\cos\pars{a} + 1
\over x^{2} - 2x\cos\pars{a} + 1}\,{\dd x \over x}
\\[3mm]&=
\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{x + p} \over x}\,\dd x
+\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{x + p^{*}} \over x}\,\dd x
-\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{x - p} \over x}\,\dd x
-\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{x - p^{*}} \over x}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> However,
>   \begin{align}
> &\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{x + b} \over x}\,\dd x
> =-\ln\pars{b}\ln\pars{\epsilon}
> +\int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{x/b + 1} \over x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-\ln\pars{b}\ln\pars{\epsilon}
> +\int_{\epsilon/b}^{1/b}{\ln\pars{x+ 1} \over x}\,\dd x
> =-\ln\pars{b}\ln\pars{\epsilon}
> +\int_{-\epsilon/b}^{-1/b}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-\ln\pars{b}\ln\pars{\epsilon}
> -\int_{-\epsilon/b}^{-1/b}{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x
> =-\ln\pars{b}\ln\pars{\epsilon}
> -\int_{-\epsilon/b}^{-1/b}{\rm Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\,\dd x
> \end{align}
>   $$
> \begin{array}{|c|}\hline\\ \quad
> \int_{\epsilon}^{1}{\ln\pars{x + b} \over x}\,\dd x
> =-\ln\pars{b}\ln\pars{\epsilon} + {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{\epsilon \over b}}
> -{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 \over b}}
> \quad\\ \\ \hline
> \end{array}
> $$

Since $\ds{pp^{*} = 1}$, we get in the limit $\ds{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}$:
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x^{2} + 2x\cos\pars{a} + 1
\over x^{2} - 2x\cos\pars{a} + 1}\,{\dd x \over x}
\\[3mm]&=-{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 \over p}}
-{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 \over p^{*}}}
+{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over p}
+{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over p^{*}}
\\[3mm]&=-\bracks{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-p} + {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\,{1 \over p}}}
+\bracks{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{p} + {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{1 \over p}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x^{2} + 2x\cos\pars{a} + 1
> \over x^{2} - 2x\cos\pars{a} + 1}\,{\dd x \over x}
> \\[3mm]&=-\bracks{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\expo{\ic a}}
> +{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{-\expo{-\ic a}}}
> +\bracks{{\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{\ic a}} + {\rm Li}_{2}\pars{\expo{-\ic a}}}
> \end{align}
>   This is the general solution for $\ds{a \in {\mathbb R}}$. The OP proposed solution is found when $\ds{0 \leq a \leq \pi}$. A little later, I'll explain how to handle the general case by means of the DiLogarithm Inversion Formula.

Comment: As soon as complex numbers enter the frame, the function $\ln$ stops to be well defined. Hence what this "solution" does is to hide the problem behind misapplications of notations. (Fortunately, rigorous answers are on the page.)

Comment: You're right concerning the different $\large \ln$-branchs. However, the solution turns out to be right: An odd function of $\large\cos\left(a\right)$ and a periodic function of $\large a$ which is reduced to the OP proposed solution when $\large a \in \left[0,\pi\right)$. I agree my $\large\ln$-handling is somehow loosely done. I'll check my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may write
\begin{align*}
I := \int_{0}^{1} \log \left( \frac{x^{2} + 2x\cos\alpha + 1}{x^{2} - 2x\cos\alpha + 1} \right) \cdot \frac{dx}{x}
&= \int_{-1}^{1} \log (x^{2} + 2x\cos\alpha + 1) \cdot \frac{dx}{x} \\
&= 2 \Re \int_{-1}^{1} \log (1 + x e^{i\alpha}) \cdot \frac{dx}{x}.
\end{align*}
Now shifting the contour to the upper semicircular arc $\displaystyle x = e^{i(\pi - t)}$ $\displaystyle (0 \leq t \leq \pi)$, we have
\begin{align*}
I &= 2 \Re \int_{0}^{\pi} -i \log (1 - e^{i(\alpha-t)}) \, dt
= \int_{\alpha-\pi}^{\alpha} 2 \Im \log (1 - e^{it}) \, dt.
\end{align*}
By noting that
\begin{equation*}
2 \Im \log (1 - e^{it}) = \begin{cases} t + \pi, & -\pi < t < 0 \\ t - \pi, & 0 < t < \pi \end{cases},
\end{equation*}
for $\displaystyle 0 < \alpha < \pi$ we obtain the desired result. For general $\displaystyle \alpha$, we can also prove that
\begin{equation*}
\int_{0}^{1} \log \left( \frac{x^{2} + 2x\cos\alpha + 1}{x^{2} - 2x\cos\alpha + 1} \right) \cdot \frac{dx}{x}
= \frac{\pi^{2}}{2} - \pi |\alpha|
\quad \text{for } |\alpha| \leq \pi \text{ and extended by periodicity}.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\ln\frac{x^{2}+2x\cos a+1}{x^{2}-2x\cos a+1}\cdot \frac{1}{x}\ dx\\
 =& \int_{0}^{1}\int_a^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{2\sin t\ }{x^{2}-2x\cos t+1}- \frac{2\sin t\ }{x^{2}+2x\cos t+1}\right) dt \ dx\\
=& \int_{0}^{1}\int_a^{\pi/2} \frac{4\sin t\ (1+x^2)}{x^4-2x^2\cos2t +1}dt \ dx\\
 =& \int_a^{\pi/2} 2\tan^{-1}\frac{x-\frac1x}{2\sin t}\bigg|_0^1\ dt = \int_a^{\pi/2}\pi \ dt =\frac{\pi^{2}}{2}-\pi a  \\
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

I understand that this an old question but I would like to share my 2 cents. First of all we recall the following Fourier identities:

**Lemma 1:** Let $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin nx}{n} = \frac{\pi-x}{2} \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos n x}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}  -\frac{\pi x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{4} \tag{1}$$

**Lemma 2:** Let $x \in [-\pi, \pi]$ then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \sin nx}{n} = - \frac{x}{2} \Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \cos nx}{n^2} = \frac{x^2}{4} - \frac{\pi^2}{12} \tag{2}$$

**Lemma 3:** It holds that:

$$\ln \left ( 1 - 2x \cos a + x^2 \right ) = -2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n \cos na}{n} \tag{3}$$

Hence for $a \in [0, \pi]$

\begin{align*}
\ln \left ( \frac{1+2x \cos a + x^2}{1-2x \cos a + x^2} \right ) &= \ln \left ( 1 + 2x \cos a + x^2 \right ) - \ln \left ( 1 - 2x \cos a + x^2 \right ) \\ 
 &=-2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^n \cos na}{n}  + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n \cos na}{n} \\ 
 &= -2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left ( (-x)^n - x^n \right ) \cos na}{n} \\
 &= 4 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1} \cos (2n+1)a}{2n+1} 
\end{align*}

since $(-x)^n - x^n$ is $0$ whenever $n$ is even. Hence,

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \ln \left( \frac{1+2x\cos a+x^2}{ 1-2x \cos a+x^2 } \right) \, \mathrm{d}x &= 4\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n+1} \cos (2n+1)a}{2n+1} \, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
 &=4 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(2n+1)a}{2n+1} \int_{0}^{1} x^{2n} \, \mathrm{d}x \\ 
 &=4 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2n+1)a}{(2n+1)^2} 
\end{align*}

This is nothing else than $\chi_2$ [Legendre function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function) directly associated with the series in $(1)$, $(2)$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2n+1)a}{(2n+1)^2} & = \mathfrak{Re} \left ( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{i(2n+1)a}}{(2n+1)^2}  \right )  \\ 
 &=\frac{1}{2}\mathfrak{Re} \left ( \mathrm{Li}_2 \left ( e^{ia} \right )  - \mathrm{Li}_2 \left ( - e^{ia} \right ) \right )
\end{align*}

The real part of $\mathrm{Li}_2(e^{ix})$ is equation $(1)$ whereas the real part of $\mathrm{Li}_2(-e^{ix})$ is equation $(2)$. Thus,

\begin{align*}
4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos (2n+1)a}{\left ( 2n+1 \right )^2} &= 2 \left ( \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{\pi a}{2} + \frac{a^2}{4} - \frac{a^2}{4} + \frac{\pi^2}{12} \right ) \\ 
 &=\frac{\pi^2}{2} - \pi a
\end{align*}

Because the LHS is even so must be the RHS. So, the result can be extended for $a \in [-\pi, 0]$. Therefore,

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \ln \left( \frac{1+2x\cos a+x^2}{ 1-2x \cos a+x^2 } \right) \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi^2}{2} - \pi \left| a \right|$$